# How to get this regular expression

Tags: regex, netbeans, qregularexpression

I have this piece of code:

```
<a href="http://www.fnac.pt/Memorial-do-Convento-Texto-em-Analise-Varios/a242166" class="fontbigger">Memorial do Convento - Texto em Análise</a>
```

...and I want to get this part:

```
Memorial do Convento - Texto em Análise
```

How do I do it?  I have tried this:

```
<a href="[^<]+" class=".+">(.+)</a>
```

...but the first `[^<]` doesn't work cause it recognizes only this:

```
http://www.fnac.pt/Memorial-do-Convento-Texto-em-Analise-Varios/
```

Comment: Use an HTML Parser

Comment: "Lazy" answer: >.*<
You just have to remove < and  >. The part where you want to leave this '-' between convento and texto - this is hard part. In your html You could mark this specific dash as diffrent character (fe '~'). And then in java strings methods remove any dashes but this one, and at the end change ~ to -.

Comment: You might be better off using the `split` function using a `/` as delimiter. Then you could select the 2nd element in the resulting array (0th element is the 1st element).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [captured](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatch.html#captured) with this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/hQ7kS7/1):

```
QRegularExpression regex("<a.*?>(.*?)<\\/\\s*a\\s*>", QRegularExpression::MultilineOption);
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(resultHTML);
QString output = match.captured(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried out this regex and it worked

> >([^<>]+)<

However parsing HTML with regex isn't the best option

Comment: it worked? it didn't... yes, i understand that its not the best option but it is how the teacher wants...

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iH5wG0/1
Don't forget the () is a capturing group that you need to access afterwards

Comment: ah okay, and how would you get the link? `http://www.fnac.pt/Memorial-do-Convento-Texto-em-Analise-Varios/a242166`